# Finding texts of anchor tags which are children of specific class named div

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class= ""></div>
 <div class= "inner">
   <a href= "..." class="innera">text1</a>
   <a href= "..." class="innera">text2</a>
   <a href= "..." class="innnera">text3</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Lets say there is an outer div which holds couple of child divs. First one has no class name second one includes anchor tags. And the page has a lot of divs class named "outer". How can I get texts inside these a tags? And I want to count the number of anchor tags' texts inside div class="inner". Because page has a lot of divs with class named="outer" and these divs holds different number of a href tags inside child div class named="inner".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get `a` inside `div.outer > div.inner` do loop

```
outers = soup.select('div.outer')
for inner in outers:
  atags = inner.select('div.inner a')
  print(len(atags))
  for a in atags:
    print(a['href'])
```